# Arrange order of objects inside $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering if it possbile to change the order of objects inside a scope. I have a `$scope.movies` And now that scope is ordered by ID. So when I console log the `$scope.movies` it looks like this,

```
{"id":1,"title":"The Town","release_date":"2010-10-21","image":"/zX4fKmDXKGt4hlzhAJirdlRKFgO.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T19:57:58.449Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T19:57:58.449Z","movie_id":"23168","imdb_rating":"7.6"},
{"id":2,"title":"Interstellar","release_date":"2014-11-06","image":"/nBNZadXqJSdt05SHLqgT0HuC5Gm.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T19:58:16.600Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T19:58:16.600Z","movie_id":"157336","imdb_rating":"8.7"},
{"id":3,"title":"Django Unchained","release_date":"2013-01-16","image":"/5WJnxuw41sddupf8cwOxYftuvJG.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:22.411Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:22.411Z","movie_id":"68718","imdb_rating":"8.5"},
{"id":4,"title":"Moonrise Kingdom","release_date":"2012-05-30","image":"/uw88gWDC0W7AAEhMeQmtdXFV7yR.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:41.054Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:41.054Z","movie_id":"83666","imdb_rating":"7.8"},
{"id":5,"title":"Gone Girl","release_date":"2014-10-01","image":"/gdiLTof3rbPDAmPaCf4g6op46bj.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-05T09:05:08.424Z","updated_at":"2015-12-05T09:05:08.424Z","movie_id":"210577","imdb_rating":"8.2"}
```

But I want to arrange the data by release date, so it would look like this,

```
{"id":1,"title":"The Town","release_date":"2010-10-21","image":"/zX4fKmDXKGt4hlzhAJirdlRKFgO.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T19:57:58.449Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T19:57:58.449Z","movie_id":"23168","imdb_rating":"7.6"},
{"id":4,"title":"Moonrise Kingdom","release_date":"2012-05-30","image":"/uw88gWDC0W7AAEhMeQmtdXFV7yR.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:41.054Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:41.054Z","movie_id":"83666","imdb_rating":"7.8"},
{"id":3,"title":"Django Unchained","release_date":"2013-01-16","image":"/5WJnxuw41sddupf8cwOxYftuvJG.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:22.411Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:22.411Z","movie_id":"68718","imdb_rating":"8.5"},
{"id":5,"title":"Gone Girl","release_date":"2014-10-01","image":"/gdiLTof3rbPDAmPaCf4g6op46bj.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-05T09:05:08.424Z","updated_at":"2015-12-05T09:05:08.424Z","movie_id":"210577","imdb_rating":"8.2"}
{"id":2,"title":"Interstellar","release_date":"2014-11-06","image":"/nBNZadXqJSdt05SHLqgT0HuC5Gm.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T19:58:16.600Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T19:58:16.600Z","movie_id":"157336","imdb_rating":"8.7"},
```

So is it possible to change the order of objects inside a $scope using javascript?

I was using `orderBy release_date` in my ng-repeat. But for my html structure I had to put the movies into rows. Using this,

```
$scope.toRows = function(arr, total){
  var i = 0, rows = [];
  while(i < arr.length){
    i % total == 0 && rows.push([]);
    rows[rows.length-1].push(arr[i++])
  }
  return rows
};
$scope.moviesRows = $scope.toRows($scope.movies, 6);
```

And then the `orderBy` doesn't work propperly anymore because it places the first items of the `$scope.movies` in the rows and then does the `orderBy` on the objects in the rows. So it first places all the objects by order of ID in the rows, and then orders the objects in row by release_date.

*** EDIT ***

It apears that the order of the JSON output doesn't matter to how Angular places the objects.

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.release_date) - new Date(a.release_date);
});
```

Orders by release date in the object, and also in the console. But Angular still put the objects in by ID.

Comment: How do you want to display them/?

Comment: I've explained it a bit more in the question. I can't use orderBy because I'm placing my results in table rows. In this situation the ng-repeat first places the objects by id in a row, and then filters the objects in that row by release date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the orderBy filter to achieve what you want. Take a look at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Anyway, if you make a lot of collection manipulation then you'd better take a look to one of the several good libraries for this, like UnderscoreJS, Lodash, etc.

I use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) for it, but is just a preference.

**AS PER FURTHER REQUIREMENTS:**

You have to order the array before dividing it into chuncks so inject $filter on the controler and do this:

```
var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
$scope.orderedMovies = orderBy($scope.movies, "release_date", false);
$scope.moviesRows = $scope.toRows($scope.orderedMovies, 6);
```

Comment: I can't use `orderBy`. For my html structure I want to place every 6 items in a table row. So what Angular does is take the first 6 objects, places them in a row and then do the orderBy. Then take the second set of 6 objects, place them in the second row and do the order by. So first it orders on ID and then on release date.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but I'm getting an error. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry, I got the wrong variable. I've corrected the answer. Try this: $scope.orderedMovies = orderBy($scope.movies, "release_date", false);

Comment: Yup. I was just trying to figure out what variable was wrong. We came to the same conclusion at the same time. Great solution by the way. What is the ` false` argument for by the way?

Comment: If you set to true it reverses the order

Comment: Ah okay. I removed the argument and it was the same order. But yes, true and false. Thank you very much.